# How is select * from table stored in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL sever. My stored procedure has below statement

```
insert into [destination_table]

select * from [source_table]
```

Both tables have same schema. New column is added to both the tables and column is not null.
In this case do I need to compile the stored procedure again.

Comment: Yes. And using * is a bad practice.

Comment: You might want to read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad Habits to kick: using select * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: And using an `INSERT` *without* explicitly specifying which columns to insert into is also consider bad practice ...

Comment: I understand this is bad practice. This is old code in production since.

Comment: Can some one tell me how the definition of stored procedure stored in database. Will the select statement * will be replaced with column names.

Comment: @Deepthi it is just `select col1, col2, col3, .... from sourceTable`

Comment: @Deepthi - if you *know* it's bad practice, and you're prepared to have to "recompile" the procedure, why not just take the 30 seconds it takes now to replace the code with one that doesn't use `select *` and that does have an explicit column list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case do I need to compile the stored procedure again.

There is a bit of misconception here. You don't have to recompile the procedure, SQL Server will do that for you whenever SQL Server thinks it is necessary.

In this case the plan will be evicted from the plan cache and replaced with a new plan automatically when the procedure is executed the next time after the changes to the structures.